# wix mobile not able to fit javascript embedding on mobile version

Tags: javascript, velo

i have been having problems in wix mobile website version I have a javascript quoter embedded on the desktop version now how do i make that fit in the mobile dimension? any tips on getting that done [www.yourfamiliesfirst.com/tq](http://www.yourfamiliesfirst.com/tq) is where it is i have resized the first page of the quoter where you put in your information and what not. i had to scale the image and push it out of the box to fit the screen, problem is when second page after that loads its not proportional to the mobile version and it looks like the page being displayed is greater than the mobile screen. Please help me out as i have no coding skills to be able to code my way out of it but I'm open to suggestions. Thank you for whoever takes the time of reading this and give me a suggestion much love god bless.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @exodus seems like you're running into responsive site issues. Normally you could resolve it by developing with mobile-first in mind by setting @media responsive CSS.

I'm not too familiar with Wix, however I did find this [Wix documentation](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-mobile-friendly-view-layout-issues) here which guides you through having a mobile-friendly view and layout.

Comment: I will check it out and see if that helps, I know there must be a way they do have something called corvid which can write code if i don't find it in that document then I will see if there is a code that decrease the size of it somehow. If i don't figure it out I will just figure out. Need to find out how to access the design features and see if we can alter it's dimensions for it to fit on mobile. Will update what happens on my journey thank you halmon for your reply. Gona check this wix documentation now and see were the current takes me lol.